# Forcing Refresh of Non Visible Android Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anyone know a way to force a refresh/paint of a non-visible layout?

I have a complex application whereby one of the layouts might be non visible at the moment but we want to convert it to a bitmap and show it in another, smaller, scaled, visible layout.

I can easily copy a layout to a bitmap, then place that bitmap into an ImageView in the smaller visible window.  But the problem we are running into is that if views are being changed, removed or added in the non-visible window, Android is not actually painting it.  Thus the fetched bitmap that is placed in the smaller visible layout is stale and static.

So is there a way to force the non visible layout to do a repaint?

Answer (score 0):

Extend `LinearLayout` and override `onMeasure` function, return your full layout size (onscreen + offscreen). Use this layout as your non visible layout

This code might get you started..

```
public class YourLayout extends LinearLayout {
  private Context myContext;

  public YourLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    /*
     *  Magic!!!  Android doesn't draw parts of layout which is offscreen. Since YourLinear layout has some offscreen part
     *  its offscreen portions didn't get drawn. 
     *  This onMeasure function determines how much pixel of a layout need to be drawn. 
     *  widthMeasureSpec        ->  Width of YourLayout onscreen
     *  heightMeasureSpec       ->  height of YourLayout on screen
     *  your_view_offscreen_width   ->  width of offscreen part
     *  your_view_offscreen_height->   height of offscreen part
     *  So heightMeasureSpec + your_view_offscreen_height draws complete height of YourLayout whether it is onscreen or offscreen. 
     *  So widthMeasureSpec + your_view_offscreen_width draws complete width of YourLayout whether it is onscreen or offscreen
     */
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec + your_view_offscreen_width, heightMeasureSpec + your_view_offscreen_height);
   }
}
```

Now you can use this layout as your non visible layout.. ie if you are using xml to layout you can use it like this

```
 <com.your.package.YourLayout layout_width="fill_parent" layout_height="fill_parent"
  ......
 >
```

Comment: Thanks Krishnabhadra!  But that's not quite what I was getting at.  When I say "non-visible" I don't mean off-screen.  I mean the layout is no longer active - it has been replaced on screen by a different layout (i.e. I called setContentView() to change the visible layout).  I'm an Android noob so maybe I am using the wrong terms.